# How to add list of people from a domain in Office 365 to an Azure group in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I would like to extract the list of people belonging to a specific domain (for example with email like `@mydomain.mycomp.com`) and add them in an Azure security group (for example `G-MY-GROUP_L`) using PowerShell. There are several thousands people in each domain.

How can I achieve this using PowerShell? Or, is there an interface which can achieve this manually?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic group should do the trick, below are article that goes over setting it up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-create-rule

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-dynamic-membership